# How does Destro's mask move?

Tags: gi-joe

*Note that I am only referring to the 80's cartoon/toys or the Marvel comic series, NOT the recent movies which use Nanomites*.

In the original G.I. Joe: Real American Hero tv show and comics, Destro has a mask made of [forged Beryllium steel](http://gijoe.wikia.com/wiki/Destro_(RAH)).

In both the show and comics, the metal mask is shaped to his head/face and moves with his mouth movements and facial expressions. Is it ever explained *how* this is possible?

[image: destro yells]

Comment: Nanobots, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe it's a complex fabric interwoven with beryllium designed to be form fitting and slimming, as well as making a fashion statement.  It allows for full movement, so as not to impede the wearer, while at the same time allowing for maximum intimidation of enemies.